# R: lapply, receiving unused argument error of my code

Tags: r, data.table, lapply

I am trying to use a function to aggregate my data into 5 minute time interval, but I cannot understand the error I am recieving

my data is described below.

```
> head(BB)
                   V1    423 470      473 626
1 2018-02-01 00:00:00  0.000   0  0.00000   0
2 2018-02-01 00:01:00 27.750   0  0.00000   0
3 2018-02-01 00:02:00 60.375   0 39.50000   0
4 2018-02-01 00:03:00 79.500   0 54.00000   0
5 2018-02-01 00:04:00  0.000   0 57.00000   0
6 2018-02-01 00:05:00  0.000  24 60.33333   0
```

the code I am using is

```
f <- function(x){
  y <- x[x != 0]
  mean(y, na.rm = TRUE)
}

BB<-BB[, lapply(.SD, f), by = cut(as.POSIXct(V1), "5 mins")]
```

I used this code to get the average value of the 5 rows excluding 0s.

but the error I am receiving is

```
Error in `[.data.frame`(BB, , lapply(.SD, f), by = cut(as.POSIXct(V1),  : 
  unused argument (by = cut(as.POSIXct(V1), "5 mins"))
```

i would appreciate some advice to this error.

EDITED

```
structure(list(V1 = structure(c(1517410800, 1517410860, 1517410920, 
1517410980, 1517411040, 1517411100), class = c("POSIXct", "POSIXt"
), tzone = ""), `423` = c(0, 27.75, 60.375, 79.5, 0, 0), `470` = c(0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 24), `473` = c(0, 0, 39.5, 54, 57, 60.3333333333333
), `626` = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0)), row.names = c(NA, 6L), class = c("data.table", 
"data.frame"))
```

Comment: The code seems good to me, are you sure you are running this as shown? Probably restart your R session and try again.

Comment: I am pretty sure I am running this as shown. for further example I was add my data set using dput in my edited question.

Comment: @Ronak Shah I have tried restarting my R session, still doesnt work. Could you do the favor to further explain what the error means?

Comment: Works fine for me without any error for the data you have shared.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess that the `data.table` package is not loaded?

When doing

```
BB<-BB[, lapply(.SD, f), by = cut(as.POSIXct(V1), "5 mins")]
```

I get the same error, when putting

```
library(data.table)
BB<-BB[, lapply(.SD, f), by = cut(as.POSIXct(V1), "5 mins")]
```

it works.